# Adding gesture to UITextView cancels default behavior

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

I wanted to add a single tap gesture to a `UITextView` so that when my save dialog is opened I can cancel it by tapping the `UITextView`. However when I do that it cancels the normal single tap behavior of the textview. Now when I single tap on the text without the save drawer out it does nothing. The tap does trigger with the callback method correctly but it cancels the default action of the UITextView, (to place the cursor wherever you tapped).

```
// Add gesture to cancel saving
let singleCodeTextViewTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("codeTextViewTapped"))
singleCodeTextViewTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
codeTextView.addGestureRecognizer(singleCodeTextViewTap)

func codeTextViewTapped() {
    if saveDrawerOut {
        moveFilenameBannerOffScreen()
        saveAsTextField.text = ""
    }
}
```

How can I enable the default behavior of the UITextView while having a single tap gesture?

**EDIT**
I tried adding `cancelsTouchesInView = false` and that does not seem to work although it would seem like the correct answer. So now my code looks like this:

```
singleCodeTextViewTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("codeTextViewTapped"))
singleCodeTextViewTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
singleCodeTextViewTap.cancelsTouchesInView = false
codeTextView.addGestureRecognizer(singleCodeTextViewTap)
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the `delegate` of `singleCodeTextViewTap` to your view controller, implement `gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:` and return `false` if `saveDrawerOut` is `true`.

Comment: Awesome, I am assuming I need to adopt some sort of protocol for this? Which protocol would that be?

Comment: You want `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate`.

Comment: Thank you. I figured it was that but I wanted to double check.

Comment: This also does not work for me. I'll add an edit to the question, but `gestureRecognizerShouldBegin` is returning true and the field is just not getting focus.

Answer (score 1):

You could also set the `cancelsTouchesInView` to `false`. So it would be

```
singleCodeTextViewTap.cancelsTouchesInView = false
```

This would allow the gesture to be recognized and forwarded to your `UITextView`

Comment: That does not seem to be working. I added it and the textview is not getting focus or moving the caret to the correct position when I tap. If I remove the gesture it of course works

Answer (score 1):

Try `singleCodeTextViewTap.cancelsTouchesInView = false`

It should let multiple gesture recognizers live in harmony with each other.